# Is there a way to change the prompt on an embedded IPython shell, or to run an arbitrary function before the shell returns to the next prompt?

Tags: python, ipython

I am embedding an IPython Shell into my python program as a way to interact with that internal state directly (I am building a debugger). Every time the shell return for input (by printing [1]: for example), I want to be able to display some internal state of the system by calling a function that prints some values. I there any way to do this?

Comment: This might help... https://waylonwalker.com/custom-ipython-prompt/

Comment: This was quite helpful thank you.